# display block not working properly

Tags: html, css, display

I am facing some issue with display block which I have put here with simplification.

```css
.parent
{
  width:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.first
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width:30px;
}

.second
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span class="first">first</span>
<span class="second">second</span>
</div>
```

Revamping the question and its was quite confusing earlier. In above code snippet, `.second` width is limited to its content. I want `.second` to extend to end of the parent container `.parent` . I have tried using `display: block` instead of `inline-block` for `.second` but its not working. Please suggest how to do it?

Comment: i honestly can't even tell what you're asking

Comment: That's what floats do. Use flexbox instead.

Comment: @JohnHaugeland have updated to make it clear.

Comment: "its not working" is not an improvement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if I got your point you can use `overflow:hidden` and while you use a `<span>` you will need to add `display:block` . Additional *No need for `display:block` if this is a `div`*

```
.second
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
  display : block;
}
```

***Demo***

```css
.parent
{
  width:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.first
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width:30px;
}

.second
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color:white;
  overflow:hidden;
  display : block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="first">first</span>
  <span class="second">second</span>
</div>
```